# Accessing variables after asynchronous jQuery getJSON calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, getjson

I'm new to asynchronous Javascript calls, so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access a certain object's data after it has been modified by getJSON calls.

I have an object with an empty array (words) and a mainMethod and a subMethod. The mainMethod gets some JSON and calls subMethod multiple times based on the JSON data. subMethod accesses a different JSON file and uses that to populate the object's empty array (words).

When I create the object, I call mainMethod. I want to get the object's array but only after it's populated by the JSON calls.

I know it has to do something with deferred methods or something, but I keep getting a blank array in the call. How do I do this? Thanks!

Code for the object:

```
    function Something(numTerms){
        var self=this;
        this.words=[];
        this.wordsNeeded=numTerms;
        this.mainMethod = function(){
            $.getJSON("external JSON url", function(data) {
                var setIds=self.getDifferentSets(data, self.wordsNeeded).ids;
                for(var i=0; i<setIds.length; i++){
                    self.subMethod(setIds[i]);
                }   

            });
        }
     this.getDifferentSets= function(data, num){
        var obj= {};
        obj.ids=[];
        obj.wordsFound=0;
        var currSet=0;
        while(obj.wordsFound<num){
                obj.ids.push(data.sets[currSet].id);
                obj.wordsFound+=data.sets[currSet].term_count;
                currSet++;
        }
        return obj;
    }
        this.subMethod= function(id){
            $.getJSON("some other external JSON url", function(data) {
                var numberTerms= data.terms.length;
                var terms=[];
                if(self.wordsNeeded<numberTerms) numberTerms=self.wordsNeeded;

                for(var i=0;i<numberTerms;i++){
                    var word= new Object();
                    word.term=data.terms[i].term;
                    word.definition=data.terms[i].definition;
                    terms.push(word);
                }
                for(var i=0;i<terms.length;i++){
                    var word= {"term":terms[i].term, "definition":terms[i].definition};
                    self.words.push(word); //Changing the object's variable
                }
                self.wordsNeeded-=numberTerms;
            });
        }
    }
```

Creating the Object:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#fetch_button").click(function(){
           var num=Number($("#numTerms").val());
           var some= new Something(num);
           some.mainMethod();
           var words=some.words; //How can I get the final value of some.words AFTER it has been changed by the JSON calls?
        });
    })
```

Comment: When calling some.mainMethod(), in your fetch buttin, the task is asynchronous, meaning that the var words, just after, will not wait for the call to finish and some.words will be empty. To properly get the catch the data, you need to call another function AFTER you have received the data, in the function attached to getJson

Comment: But then how do I access the result of this other function that I call after receiving the data in my  $("#fetch_button").click block?

Comment: you cannot get the result of the function directly afer calling it, as it is asynchronous, you need to wait :). That's why you have to declare a new function. Example : user click the buton, a progress bar appear and you call the getJson function, once it is done you fetch the data, hide the progress bar, and finally access the data you just got

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `return this` in the main function

```
function Something(numTerms){
    var self=this;
    //Blah blah blah

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that. Then, if I do console.log(some), it does show that Something does have the right number of words. But then, I try to console.log(some.words) it still returns undefined.